# loading a yii widget form returning error

Tags: yii, components

i have a tabs in view by which in one tab i want to show a form through a widget call.

`<div class="tabcontent" id="country2">
                  <div class="No-Time">No Reviews !
                  <?php $this->widget('Review');?>
                  </div>
                   </div>`

Created the `Review` model for this.Then i create the component

```
<?php 
class Review extends CWidget
{
public $title='Review';
public $visible=true; 
public function run()
{
    if($this->visible)
    {
        $this->renderContent();
    }
}

protected function renderContent()
{

    $merchant_id = Yii::app()->user->id;
    $model  =  new Review;

    $this->performAjaxValidation($model);
$valid  = $model->validate();

    if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='review-form')
    {
            echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
            Yii::app()->end();
    }
    $this->render('Review',array('model'=>$model));
}

protected function performAjaxValidation($model)
{
        if(isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax']==='review-form')
        {
                echo CActiveForm::validate($model);
                Yii::app()->end();
        }
}
}
?>
```

This is my Component View file:

```
<?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
'id'=>'review-form',
'enableAjaxValidation'=>false,
)); ?>



<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'name'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'email'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'email'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'review'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'review'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'review'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'mobile'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'mobile'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'mobile'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'status'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'status'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'status'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'website'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'website'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'website'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'avtar'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'avtar'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'avtar'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'date'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'date'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'date'); ?>
</div>


<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit'); ?>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="merchant" id="merchant-id" />
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>

</div>
```

Having this error return. Dont know why this occured.

```
 Review and its behaviors do not have a method or closure named "isAttributeRequired".
```

Comment: Do you have a model called `Review`?

Comment: as i said earlier i have the model `Review`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rename your component to something other than `Review`. The error is because the line `$model= new Review` creates an instance of the Review component rather than the Review model.